# How to simulate window size to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating a module that allows user to simulate the view of a webpage. I have 3 buttons to dynamically change div sizes, which represents the view of the webpage.

This is similar to wordpress customization, it's just that, I can not seem to have it replicated on screen change.

The webpage is contained in a div, the collapse feature on mobile is not working on div width change, but works when I actually resize the browser window.

Edit:

Here is the code:

The div is contained in

```
<div class="site-builder-container">
```

Ok, so this site-builder-container contains code I need to edit in-page, here is the actual code with the navbar

```
<div class="site-builder-container">
<div class="site-builder-header">
    <h2 class="site-builder-header-text">Bloph</h2>
    <span class="site-builder-slogan">Online Blogging Community</span>
</div>
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-main">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!--<img src="~/Content/Images/bloph_logo.png" class="header-image-collapse visible-xs" />-->
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="navbar-menu-link active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-menu-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-menu-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-menu-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-menu-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-menu-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-menu-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-menu-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-menu-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-menu-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-menu-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-menu-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-menu-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-menu-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-menu-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I change it when a button is click and use the script:

```
$(".site-builder-container").animate({ width: "300px" });
```

Comment: We will need some code if you want us to help!

Comment: `div` is the wrong element. You need an `iframe` for that.

Comment: I provided the code I used. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I can't actually use iframe, I am not loading the site from an external source, I have to edit it in-page